# how to run ng-repeat or forEach of angular on complex json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where I'm getting list of complex JSON data(nested type).I'm new to `AngularJS`, not getting solution to run `ng-repeat` or `forEach` over that.

My returned data is like below.

```
[{
  "studPersonalDetails": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Digvijay",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Singh",
    "fatherName": "abac",
    "motherName": "abc",
    "dob": "5/7/1990 12:00:00 AM"
  },
  "clients": {
    "clientID": 1,
    "clientName": null,
    "clientDescriptions": null
  },
  "studentAddress": {
    "address1": "12",
    "address2": "12",
    "city": "21",
    "state": "212",
    "pin": 2
  },
  "courseDetails": {
    "courseID": 12,
    "courseName": "12",
    "courseDetail": null
  },
  "studentContacts": {
    "email": "12",
    "alternatePhone": "12",
    "phone": "qw"
  }
}, {
  "studPersonalDetails": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Anil",
    "middleName": "kumar",
    "lastName": "Sharma",
    "fatherName": "bac",
    "motherName": "bac",
    "dob": "2/11/1989 12:00:00 AM"
  },
  "clients": {
    "clientID": 1,
    "clientName": null,
    "clientDescriptions": null
  },
  "studentAddress": {
    "address1": "21",
    "address2": "21",
    "city": "5456",
    "state": "8",
    "pin": 7
  },
  "courseDetails": {
    "courseID": 58,
    "courseName": "58",
    "courseDetail": null
  },
  "studentContacts": {
    "email": "12",
    "alternatePhone": "12",
    "phone": "abc"
  }
}]
```

This is the response returned by API. 
Any help would be appreciated!Thanks!!

Comment: what you wanna to display ?

Comment: Is your json JSON.parse'd and assigned to a variable?

Comment: I have to run ng-repeat to render data in html. Thanks

Comment: please share expected output.There different way to use this nested json using ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks to @Rajesh,@jenjis.Thanks  for quick response and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22246/).

```html
<div ng-repeat="currentRow in data">
  <span>{{currentRow.studPersonalDetails.name}}</span>
  <span>{{currentRow.studPersonalDetails.lastName}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see an angular ngRepeat example with your data [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5zumt7ra/3/)

First, create a controller with your data:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.datalist = [  
    {  
    "studPersonalDetails":{  
        "id":0,
        "name":"Digvijay",
        "middleName":"",
        "lastName":"Singh",
        "fatherName":"Shyam Bahadur Singh",
        "motherName":"ramawati Devi",
        "dob":"5/7/1990 12:00:00 AM"
    },
    "clients":{  
        "clientID":1,
        "clientName":null,
        "clientDescriptions":null
    },
    "studentAddress":{  
        "address1":"12",
        "address2":"12",
        "city":"21",
        "state":"212",
        "pin":2
    },
    "courseDetails":{  
        "courseID":12,
        "courseName":"12",
        "courseDetail":null
    },
    "studentContacts":{  
        "email":"12",
        "alternatePhone":"12",
        "phone":"qw"
    }
    },
    {  
    "studPersonalDetails":{  
        "id":0,
        "name":"Anil",
        "middleName":"kumar",
        "lastName":"Sharma",
        "fatherName":"bac",
        "motherName":"bac",
        "dob":"2/11/1989 12:00:00 AM"
    },
    "clients":{  
        "clientID":1,
        "clientName":null,
        "clientDescriptions":null
    },
    "studentAddress":{  
        "address1":"21",
        "address2":"21",
        "city":"5456",
        "state":"8",
        "pin":7
    },
    "courseDetails":{  
        "courseID":58,
        "courseName":"58",
        "courseDetail":null
    },
    "studentContacts":{  
        "email":"12",
        "alternatePhone":"12",
        "phone":"abc"
    }
    }
];
}
```

Then attach this controller to your view and use the ngRepeat to extract each top-level object from *dataList* array (during the itaration the current object has alias *data*)

Inside the repeat statement you can display requested values accessing the *data* object using dot notation:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in datalist">
    <p><span>Name</span> {{ data.studPersonalDetails.name }}</p>
    <p><span>CourseID</span> {{ data.courseDetails.courseID }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.arr = [{
  "studPersonalDetails": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Digvijay",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Singh",
    "fatherName": "Shyam Bahadur Singh",
    "motherName": "ramawati Devi",
    "dob": "5/7/1990 12:00:00 AM"
  },
  "clients": {
    "clientID": 1,
    "clientName": null,
    "clientDescriptions": null
  },
  "studentAddress": {
    "address1": "12",
    "address2": "12",
    "city": "21",
    "state": "212",
    "pin": 2
  },
  "courseDetails": {
    "courseID": 12,
    "courseName": "12",
    "courseDetail": null
  },
  "studentContacts": {
    "email": "12",
    "alternatePhone": "12",
    "phone": "qw"
  }
}, {
  "studPersonalDetails": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Anil",
    "middleName": "kumar",
    "lastName": "Sharma",
    "fatherName": "bac",
    "motherName": "bac",
    "dob": "2/11/1989 12:00:00 AM"
  },
  "clients": {
    "clientID": 1,
    "clientName": null,
    "clientDescriptions": null
  },
  "studentAddress": {
    "address1": "21",
    "address2": "21",
    "city": "5456",
    "state": "8",
    "pin": 7
  },
  "courseDetails": {
    "courseID": 58,
    "courseName": "58",
    "courseDetail": null
  },
  "studentContacts": {
    "email": "12",
    "alternatePhone": "12",
    "phone": "abc"
  }
}]
```

Using [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) you can do it like this.

```
angular.forEach($scope.arr,function(value,key){

  console.log(value.studPersonalDetails.lastName); 

})
```

Using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat),you can do it like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="oneArr in arr">
       <td> {{oneArr.studPersonalDetails.name}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mpw2X1lU2HLeUHPROSDK?p=preview)